# Sort all Columns independently form a 2d array java

Tags: java, sorting

I need to have the columns organized in increasing order. Right now I have the following done but, it is sorting the rows and not columns.Any help would be nice, ive been working on this all day. Thanks.

```
public static double[][] sortColumns(double[][] m) {
    double[][] sortedArray = new double[m.length][m.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        double[] temp = new double[m.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {

            temp[j] = m[j][i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            sortedArray[j][i] = temp[j];
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current solution, you are just mistaking on indexes, just like **David Wallace** tells you in his answer. I propose you a different answer, enumerating the possible solutions of this problem.

You have at least 4 solutions :

- instead of storing your data like you are currently doing it, use the transponate of your matrix
- implement yourself an efficient sorting algorithm that takes a bi-dimensional array and the index of a column in argument
- at each turn of you loop, fill an array with the current column, sort it, and copy it back (if you don't care about using some additional memory, do it). That is what you are currently trying to do
- transponate your matrix, sort its lines, transponate it back (if you don't want to use too much memory, use this)

I prefer the last solution, which code is :

```
public static double[][] sortColumns(double[][] m) {
    double[][] sortedArray = new double[m.length][m.length];

    // compute the transponate of m
    for (int i=0 ; i<m.length ; i++)
        for (int j=0 ; j<m[i].length ; j++)
            sortedArray[j][i] = m[i][j];

    // sort the lines of the transponate
    for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.length; i++)        
        Arrays.sort(sortedArray[i]);

    // transponate back the result of the sorting
    for (int i=0 ; i<sortedArray.length ; i++)
        for (int j=i+1 ; j<sortedArray[i].length ; j++) {
            double tmp = sortedArray[i][j]; 
            sortedArray[i][j] = sortedArray[j][i]; 
            sortedArray[j][i] = tmp; 
        }

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
temp[j] = m[j][i];
```

to

```
temp[j] = m[i][j];
```

and

```
sortedArray[j][i] = temp[j];
```

to

```
sortedArray[i][j] = temp[j];
```

then your existing algorithm will work fine.  It just means you'll be copying columns to your "temporary sorting area" instead of rows.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code I see the following line:

```
double[][] sortedArray = new double[m.length][m.length];
```

it doesn't look right to me.
you need to find length and breath of the array so i would do something like this:
length = m.length;
breath = m[0].length;

if i m not sure of all rows have same no of elements i may do that check by a for loop and initialize with the max.. wud lead to memory wastage but thats another demon to tame :)

next when we write m[x][y] x represents the rows and y represents the columns so when ur doing :

```
for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {

            temp[j] = m[j][i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(temp);
```

you are fetching all the values from a column i, assigning it to temp array and sorting the column.

hope that helps